# How to use a combobox as an object in a subprocedure paramater?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have an application that includes several combo-boxes which are populated with database values.  I am trying to write a procedure that will allow me to pass in a few parameters (query string, dataset name, combo-box) in order to populate any combo-box but I cant figure out how to use a combobox object in the procedure correctly.  Currently the DisplayMember, ValueMember, and DataSource methods are not contained by my object parameter.

*** Code below has been updated based on a sugestion, it is working, just trying to make sure I am going about this in a logical way now.

```
string cbxScheduleQuery = "SELECT SCHEDULE_ID FROM UCC_SCHEDULE_GROUP";
CbxLoad(cbxScheduleQuery, cbxSchedule);


private void CbxLoad(string query, ComboBox cbx)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            cbx.Items.Clear();
            cbx.Items.Add("");

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                cbx.Items.Add(sqlReader[0].ToString());
            }
            sqlReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error Occured");
        }
    }
```

The desired result is a procedure that can take a few simple parameters and populate any of my comboboxes without having to define a complete data source connection for each one.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd rethink the desired approach.  If you have several CBOs load one persistent dataset with several tables as one method.  Then set them up as the DataSource.  it will get messy otherwise (for instance passing in the ValueMember and DisplayMember names).  Else where, there is no need to burn a DataAdapter - just use `ExecuteReader` to fill the DataTables

Comment: I did get my version working, I was trying object and object.ComboBox as the paramater but apparently all it wanted was ComboBox.  That being said, if there is a better way to go about this I will gladly look into it.  I tried picking some key words from your post to search for examples or documentation but I dont think I found exactly what you are describing.  If you know of any references I could look at that would be great.

Comment: Been doing some reaserch on your sugestion, dont think this is exactly what you mentioned but I belive it is moving in that direction.  I have updated the post with new code, if you have any advise I am happy to hear it.